# 4 point quadratic curve

Tags: interpolation

I can define a curve that passes through 3 points using a quadratic equation:

```
ax2 + bx + c = 0
```

I would like to know is it possible to define a curve that passes through 4 points using:

```
ax3 + bx2 + cx + d = 0
```

Cheers

Comment: Yes, it is possible. In general, for any n points in a plane, you can find an (n-1)th degree (or higher) polynomial that passes through all of them. Finding these polynomial involves solving matrix equations and can sometimes get a bit messy.

Comment: You can also use a Lagrange interpolating polynomial.

Comment: @jpm is correct. For an easy formula (that works in *most* cases), see [Lagrange polynomial - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Answer (score 1):

The answer was already in the comments upon migration: Use a [Lagrange polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). The restriction "in most cases" is unnecessary; the Lagrange polynomial is completely general and yields a polynomial which interpolates the points as long as no two of them have the same $x$ coordinate; if they do, there can be no univariate function, polynomial or otherwise, that interpolates them.